# Xubuntu hotkey for immediate shutdown

Tags: xubuntu, shutdown, xfce, logging

I would like to create a two hotkeys. First for terminating all procesess and shutdown the system and turn computer off.

I have tried something but it only logged me off and then I had to confirm I want to log off and then turn off computer manually.

The second one for simple log off.

What is the command I should type in keyboard/hotkey settings? Or should I make .sh file and run it? What command for running the file should I use then?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`gksudo shutdown -h now` would come to mind, but this command requires root privileges. To execute it you would have to enter you password.

Here's a command that should work without root and shut down your PC immediately (compatible with all official Ubuntu flavors):

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

These are Xubuntu-specific:

- shutdown: `xfce4-session-logout --halt`
- restart: `xfce4-session-logout --reboot`
- log out: `xfce4-session-logout --logout`
- suspend: `xfce4-session-logout --suspend`
- hibernate: `xfce4-session-logout --hibernate`

Sources:

http://bbs.archbang.org/viewtopic.php?pid=9078#p9078

http://linux.die.net/man/1/xfce4-session-logout

Comment: Did you want `--halt` (instead of `--logout`) for the shutdown command?

Comment: And it's `--reboot` not restart.

Comment: Also interesting option might be `--fast` option to shutdown fast without saving the session.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the ['Magic SysRq key'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) which is enabled by default on Linux

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to close all processes

To *cleanly* reboot:

> Used in sequence, some of these actions can be used to cleanly end processes, flush data to disk, unmount all file systems, and restart your computer. To perform this process, press and hold the Alt + SysRq key combination and – while holding the Alt and SysRq keys down — type the following keys in order, pausing for several seconds in between each key:

```
reisub
```

To shutdown instead, press <kbd>o</kbd> instead of <kbd>b</kbd> at the end of the above sequence.

([source](http://www.howtogeek.com/119127/use-the-magic-sysrq-key-on-linux-to-fix-frozen-x-servers-cleanly-reboot-and-run-other-low-level-commands/))

Comment: The Magic SysRq key combo is an emergency shutdown procedure. I would advise against using it if you don't have to.

Comment: @Glutanimate It may be worse than clicking 'shutdown' from the menu but it's better than just doing a hardware shutdown. It asks processes to close nicely and writes data to disk before actually powering off. See the link 'Magic SysRq Key' in my answer for info about what each key does

Comment: Yes, but it still bypasses the natural shutdown procedure and should be reserved for emergency cases only. There are less radical alternatives out there.

Comment: OK, agreed with that.